# expressionengine: set_flashdata on the fly

Tags: expressionengine

Expression Engine CP has notification option, you may set set_flashdata, and it will display message.

How can I show messages dynamically, like when you edit templates and change some option, it saves it and shows message in the top without refreshing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would have to hack ee core, as there are not hooks available to trigger that type of notification.